# Web Part with more than one connection

Tags: 2007, connected-web-parts, list-view-web-part

Can I have a web part use more than one connection?

I have three web parts: Web Part A, Web Part B, & Web Part C.  Web Part C has three columns, A, B & C.  I want Web Part A to filter Web Part C on column A, and Web Part B to filter Web Part C on column B.

These are all List View Web Parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with OOTB default webparts.  You can convert these to data view webparts and utilize multiple connections.